# Squid proxy redirect to search if unable to resolve hostname

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

When not using a proxy, a hostname that does not exist results in an NX returned from the DNS server, and the web browser (Firefox in this case) is smart enough to attempt a search instead. However, when running through Squid, a non-existent hostname just returns a 'URL cannot be retrieved' error.

Is it possible to configure Squid to redirect to a search engine if the hostname cannot be resolved? I am running Squid 3.1.19 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Squid allows you to customise the error messages by editing the templates found in `/usr/share/squid/errors/<LANG>/`  directories.

Simply update the template for `ERR_DNS_FAIL`  to include a search box or a redirect to your preferred search engine.